# Why isn't StackBuilder installation of PostGIS working?

Tags: postgis, installation

I've installed PostGIS (ver. 2.0.1) on my Mac using EnterpriseDB's StackBuilder, which I also used for my PostgreSQL (9.2.2) installation. Although StackBuilder says that PostGIS is now installed, and although I have a PostGIS directory in /usr/local/PostgreSQL/9.2/, it doesn't appear to be actually installed (see queries below).

```
gregory=# select postgis_full_version();
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: select postgis_full_version();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

gregory=# create extension postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/PostgreSQL/9.2/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

and `select * from pg_available_extensions;` does not return a record for PostGIS.

Does anyone know what's up with this and how to get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to load the postgis extension to your database like

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

or load these files to your query window and run them in database

```
windows default: 
\Program files\Postgresql\8.4\share\contrib\postgis-2.0

postgis.sql
rtpostgis.sql
spatial_ref_sys.sql
topology.sql (if you want topology support)
```

Comment: Command `create extension postgis` doesn't find what it needs to run (as noted in original post) and the PostGIS directory tree installed by StackBuilder contains no .sql files.

Comment: Have you tried to search those files from hard disk ?

Comment: I just found the following files. Should I run them all (except the uninstalls) and does order matter? legacy.sql   postgis_comments.sql  rtpostgis.sql   spatial_ref_sys.sql  topology_upgrade_20_minor.sql uninstall_rtpostgis.sql
legacy_minimal.sql  postgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql rtpostgis_legacy.sql  topology.sql   uninstall_legacy.sql  uninstall_topology.sql
postgis.sql   raster_comments.sql  rtpostgis_upgrade_20_minor.sql topology_comments.sql  uninstall_postgis.sql

Comment: in mentioned order